# Leetcode not accepting correct sudoku solver algorithim

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, sudoku

I wrote a sudoku solver in Javascript for https://leetcode.com/problems/sudoku-solver/solution/. Whenever I use the same code in an IDE outside of leetcode, it solves the sudoku board fine. However, when I submit it as an answer in leetcode, it always returns a the default board parameter passed in to the function. Can anyone figure out why?

Note: The leetcode problem says to solve the board in place and not to return anything.

Error: imgur.com/a/63v7sOu

```
/**
 * @param {character[][]} board
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
 */

var solveSudoku = function(board) {
    function check(y, x, n, board){
        // Search column for n
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if (board[y][i] == n) return false;
        }
        // Search row for n
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if (board[i][x] == n) return false;
        }

        const row = Math.floor(x / 3) * 3;
        const col = Math.floor(y / 3) * 3;

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                if (board[col+i][row+j] == n) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    function solve(board){
        for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++){
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++){
                if (board[y][x] === "."){
                    for (let n = 1; n < 10; n++){
                        if(check(y, x, n, board)){
                            board[y][x] = n.toString();
                            solve(board);
                            board[y][x] = ".";
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    solve(board)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything when I run it either.  At the end `board` looks just like it did at the beginning.  I'm guessing that what's in your IDE is not the same thing you've presented here or to leetcode.

Answer (score 0):

`solveSudoku` doesn't do anything, it only defines two functions. Call `solve(board)` in the function body.

Comment: Leetcode calls `solveSudoku()`, not `solve()`. And your `solveSudoku()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to list that call in the function, however when I've tried that, it still returns the same.